# Expansion of Bose Distribution at low Temperatures

Tags: homework-and-exercises, phonons, quantum-statistics, low-temperature-physics

I have a phononic system with its distribution

$$N_B(E,T) = \frac{1}{e^{E/k_BT}-1}$$

where $E$ is the energy and $T$ the temperature of the system.

I'd like to know how to make an expansion of this at low temperatures, that is
$$E>>k_B T$$

I already googled but I haven't found anything useful

Comment: This is a basic calculus question, is it not?

Comment: So basic that I couldn't find a convincing answer

Comment: Low temperature compared to what? An expansion with respect to what? What is the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $e^{-E/k_BT}$ to get

$$N_B(E,T) = \frac{1}{e^{E/k_BT}-1}=e^{-E/k_BT}\cdot \frac{1}{1-e^{-E/k_BT}}$$

This gives you something that looks like $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ which can be expanded for $|x|<1$.